# format pandas dataframe in xlsxwriter duplicateworksheetname

Tags: python, pandas, xlsxwriter

Getting a `DuplicateWorksheetName` error while I try to write a pandas dataframe and apply some formatting using xlsxwriter.

I have not seen a similar question. I have seen questions on format not being applied selectively at header etc for which there have been some solutions.

```
import xlsxwriter
import pandas as pd

dest_filename="C:/Users/User11/Python test/sample.xlsx"
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(dest_filename, engine='xlsxwriter')
wb = writer.book
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col_1': [1, 2, 3],'col_2': [4, 5, 6],}, columns=['col_1', 'col_2'])
ws = wb.add_worksheet("Sheet1")
format1 = wb.add_format({'bg_color': '#FFC7CE','font_color': '#9C0006'})
format2 = wb.add_format({'bg_color': '#000000','font_color': '#000000'})
ws.set_column('B:P', 2)
# Set the format but not the column width.
ws.set_column('A:A', None)
ws.conditional_format('B2:P16', {'type': 'blanks','stop_if_true': True,'format': format1})
df1.to_excel(writer,sheet_name="Sheet1",)
writer.save()
```

Comment: Looks like a worksheet of that same name exists. Try changing the name of the file/sheet that you're working on.

Answer (score 2):

The "DuplicateWorksheetName" exception indicates that you are trying to create two worksheets with the same name (which Excel doesn't allow). This is happening in the `add_worksheet("Sheet1")` and `df1.to_excel(writer,sheet_name="Sheet1")` calls.

This correct way to do this is to mix Pandas with direct manipulation of the worksheet in XlsxWriter is to create the worksheet with pandas (`.to_excel()`) and then access the created worksheet and workbook objects.

See the XlsxWriter docs on [Working with Python Pandas and XlsxWriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html). Here is a working example based on your code:

```
import xlsxwriter
import pandas as pd

dest_filename="C:/Users/User11/Python test/sample.xlsx"
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(dest_filename, engine='xlsxwriter')

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col_1': [1, 2, 3],
                    'col_2': [4, 5, 6],}, 
                    columns=['col_1', 'col_2'])
df1.to_excel(writer,sheet_name="Sheet1")

# Get the xlsxwriter objects from the dataframe writer object.
wb = writer.book
ws = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

format1 = wb.add_format({'bg_color': '#FFC7CE','font_color': '#9C0006'})
format2 = wb.add_format({'bg_color': '#000000','font_color': '#000000'})

ws.set_column('B:P', 2)

ws.conditional_format('B2:P16', {'type': 'blanks',
                                 'stop_if_true': True,
                                 'format': format1})

writer.save()
```

Comment: Got it . Actually I figured it out after I posted the question. Your response has also confirmed it. Thanks.